# Symfony: Index in collection Type

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I am trying to set the label of an embedded form type (collection type).
These labels have to be different for the different collections.

For example I have two collections and an array with the labels ['label1','label2'] in die form type.

I think I need the index of the collection iteration to get the right label.

Like below i need the index for the entry_options label to get the right value of the $labels array.

Thats my buildForm Method

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $labels = ['label1', 'label2'];

        $builder
            ->add('otherForms', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => otherFormType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => $labels[$index]],
            ])
            ...
        ;
    }
```

Comment: you say you have two collections, but your code suggests, you have one mixed collection (maybe one entry for label1 and one for label2?) why do you use the CollectionType at all and don't instead jsut add two forms?

Comment: I have selected two collections for this example.
Normaly I have a flexible amount of collections for different languages.

In general I have 10+ collections.

And it would be awesome if it's possible to build the form flexible so I can add languages later and don't have to update the form type.

Comment: I have this nagging doubt, that you actually only have *one* collection, in which every sub form shall get a different label. is that accurate?

Comment: For example I have an entity with an ID "GB" and the name "Great Britain".
Now I updated the website to be multilangual.
Now I have one Entity with the ID "GB" and the name is in another Entity with a new ID, reference to the first Entity, a country contraction "en" and the translation "Great Britain". So I have an entity for every language.

Do you understand?

Comment: I did not wanted to use translation bundles.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments, I must agree that translation bundles are sometimes heavy weight and quite inconvenient.

The CollectionType usually ignores the index/key of collection items given to it, though.

Now I see two scenarios: you want to give the labels as an option to your form or [the form shall be dependent on the data (using form events)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). Your code so far suggests, that languages are set globally and will not be added on the fly in some other manner.

In the first scenario it's very simple (see below), the second scenario requires some event listener in your form, but apart from that, it's quite similar.

The essential idea is to just create the forms you need (optionally inside the pre-submit handler), since you apparently already know which forms you need from the label array:

```
foreach($labels as $index => $label) { 
    $builder->add('otherForms'.$index, otherFormType::class, [
        'label' => $label, 
        'property_path' => 'otherForms['.$index.']',
    ]);
}
```

The use of [`property_path`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path) will help you access the proper elements (however, changing the language (= key) of a translation might be difficult, but that should not happen, usually. And even if it happens, only some copy-pasta is necessary).

Your `otherForms` keys probably will be differently, but I guess you'll figure it out.

Comment: Yes I think that's an option.
But I hoped there is a solution, where I dont need a couple of forms.

Comment: @broxyl technically, "CollectionType" just creates a couple of forms... so ... unless you're willing to write your own FormType (which might be an alternative) there will always be a couple of forms

Comment: Yes I know but it creates the same form multiple times and I don't have to create multiple forms by myself.